# How to use iloc slicing on outermost level in multiindex DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a Multiindex DataFrame with pd.timestamp as toplevel index and some arbitrary parameters as second level. You can use this snippet to reproduce some mock data:

```
level0 = pd.period_range(start='2020-01-01-00:00:00', end='2020-01-01-00:01:00', freq='s')
level1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
values = np.random.rand(len(level1)*len(level0))
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([level0, level1], names=['time', 'level1'])
col = ['value']
df = pd.DataFrame(values, idx, col)
print(df)
```

Which creates the output:

```
                               value
time                level1          
2020-01-01 00:00:00 foo     0.345507
                    bar     0.147654
                    foobar  0.617000
2020-01-01 00:00:01 foo     0.430975
                    bar     0.783075
...                              ...
2020-01-01 00:00:59 bar     0.027083
                    foobar  0.553220
2020-01-01 00:01:00 foo     0.253957
                    bar     0.569881
                    foobar  0.976768
```

Now I want to take every *n*-th second as data for my further calculations. My first approach was to use `.iloc[::n]`, which works fine, if the Dataframe is unstacked first. So the code `df.unstack().iloc[::5].stack()` produces exactly my desired output:

```
                               value
time                level1          
2020-01-01 00:00:00 bar     0.147654
                    foo     0.345507
                    foobar  0.617000
2020-01-01 00:00:05 bar     0.083129
                    foo     0.591585
                    foobar  0.660372
2020-01-01 00:00:10 bar     0.460798
                    foo     0.308138
                    foobar  0.622412
...                              ...
2020-01-01 00:00:55 bar     0.700964
                    foo     0.556782
                    foobar  0.601582
2020-01-01 00:01:00 bar     0.569881
                    foo     0.253957
                    foobar  0.976768
```

However, unstacking and stacking gets hugely ressource intensive when the df becomes large. And I feel that there is a simple, elegant and 'cheap' solution, that I just can't grasp.

Is there a solution to select every *n*-th timestamp that avoids unstacking the data?

EDIT: For anyone reading this: Although jezraels' answer is a nice way to do it and tought me a few things on how to deal with the problem, it turns out for my case (month worth of secondly data and ca 300 "level1"-entries), that the `unstack().iloc[::n].stack()` method is faster and scales better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select values by first level and then slicing each 5 values, last pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.levels[0][::5]]
print(df1)

                               value
time                level1          
2020-01-01 00:00:00 foo     0.350853
                    bar     0.998113
                    foobar  0.077340
2020-01-01 00:00:05 foo     0.029292
                    bar     0.394105
                    foobar  0.375882
2020-01-01 00:00:10 foo     0.878306
                    bar     0.152500
                    foobar  0.299017
2020-01-01 00:00:15 foo     0.821039
                    bar     0.298991
                    foobar  0.496110
2020-01-01 00:00:20 foo     0.523729
                    bar     0.928747
                    foobar  0.902535
2020-01-01 00:00:25 foo     0.128496
                    bar     0.126517
                    foobar  0.802517
2020-01-01 00:00:30 foo     0.539462
                    bar     0.754518
                    foobar  0.243328
2020-01-01 00:00:35 foo     0.159771
                    bar     0.058187
                    foobar  0.508651
2020-01-01 00:00:40 foo     0.847019
                    bar     0.688022
                    foobar  0.368563
2020-01-01 00:00:45 foo     0.575865
                    bar     0.531090
                    foobar  0.756400
2020-01-01 00:00:50 foo     0.584265
                    bar     0.155704
                    foobar  0.734554
2020-01-01 00:00:55 foo     0.035894
                    bar     0.047678
                    foobar  0.746624
2020-01-01 00:01:00 foo     0.254821
                    bar     0.756032
                    foobar  0.694809
```